# Keycloak with Spring Boot 3 and multiple Realms

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I need to authenticate/authorize a Spring Boot application with Keycloak using multiple Realms.

So if the request is https://server/realm1/api.json then the realm [realm1] on Keycloak will be used, if the request is https://server/realmXYZ/api.json then the realm [realmXYZ] will be used.

**Have done**

With the following configuration (I'm using a old Keycloak 15.02)

```
# Resource Server
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/realm1
# Client Registration
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=my-client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid
# Client Provider
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/realm1
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username
```

and the following configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "keycloak.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain resourceServerFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.info("resourceServerFilterChain - Start");
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                // Token authentication
                .requestMatchers(ALLOWED_API_LIST).permitAll()
                // Single Sign Out
                .requestMatchers("/sso-logout").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );

        // ResourceServer setting
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .jwt(withDefaults()));

        // Client setting - shows the login screen
        http.oauth2Login(withDefaults());

        // Client setting - add logout handler
        http.logout(logout -> logout.addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler).logoutSuccessUrl("/"));
    }
}
```

I'm able to login with the [realm1].
When the user is unauthenticated the Keycloak Login screen is displayed and the login process is completed.

As per https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html
I thought that using a Bean for ClientRegistrationRepository will allow me to set the authorizationUrl dynamically depending on the request.
So I wrote the following

```
    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.customClientRegistration());
    }

    private ClientRegistration customClientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("keycloak")
                .clientId("mcd-client")
//                .clientSecret("")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                // Required
                .redirectUri("{baseUrl}")
                .scope("openid")
                .authorizationUri("http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/realm1")
                // Required
                .tokenUri("{baseUrl}/auth/realms/realm1/protocol/openid-connect/token")
//                .userInfoUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo")
                .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
                .jwkSetUri("http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/realm1")
                .clientName("keycloak")
                .build();
    }
```

But now Keycloak doesn't show the Login screen, instead a Json response is displayed in the browser

```
{"realm":"realm1","public_key":"M...","token-service":"http...","account-service":"","tokens-not-before":1677687677}}
```

Also, another problem will be how to create a new RegistrationClient depending on the Keycloak Realm if the InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository class is final.

Appreciate your help.